# Merging rows from different dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have two Dataframes: one with columns "Name", "Year" and "Type" and the other one with different parameters. There are 4 different types and each one has his specific parameters. Now i need to merge them together.

My approach is to use a if-function to find out the "type". For example in row two of df3 i have type 'a'.  The parameters for type 'a' are in row 3 of df4. I tried to connect them with the following code:

```
df3.ix[[2]]
s1 = df3.ix[[2]]
s2 = df4.ix[[3]]
result = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

My problem is now, that the parameters are in a seperate row and not added to row 2. Is there a chance to merge them together in one row? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Post raw input data for both dfs, your code to create them and the desired output, at the moment your question is very vague

Comment: i import the dfs directly from two different excel-files

Answer (score 1):

If `df3` has a `Type` column and `df4` has a `type` column, then the two DataFrames can be merged with

```
pd.merge(df3, df4, left_on='Type', right_on='type')
```

This is by default [an inner join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

---

```
In [13]: df3
Out[13]: 
  Name  Year   Type
1    A  2012   boat
2    B  2013    car
3    C  2011  truck
4    D  2013   boat

In [14]: df4
Out[14]: 
    type  Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3
0   boat           2           8           7
1    car           1           9           3
2  truck           5           4           2

In [15]: pd.merge(df3, df4, left_on='Type', right_on='type')
Out[15]: 
  Name  Year   Type   type  Parameter1  Parameter2  Parameter3
0    A  2012   boat   boat           2           8           7
1    D  2013   boat   boat           2           8           7
2    B  2013    car    car           1           9           3
3    C  2011  truck  truck           5           4           2
```

Note that if the column names matched exactly, then

```
pd.merge(df3, df4)
```

would merge on column names shared in common by default.

Comment: is there any kind of limit? cause it stops after 265 of more than 1800 rows

Comment: Can you construct an example which demonstrates the problem? Merging thousands of rows typically should be no problem -- at most you would end up with millions of rows in the merged DataFrame (if the key has a lot of duplicates). As long as you are not running out of memory, `pd.merge` should succeed.

Comment: Are you calling `pd.merge` in a loop? (Otherwise, how do you know it stops after 265 rows?) You should be able to merge the two DataFrames with only one call to `pd.merge`.... It would help if we could see a minimal runnable example which demonstrates the problem you are seeing.

Comment: no i don't use a loop. my file looks like the one example in your answer, just with rows and columns. My df3 hast 1858 rows and that one gets merged with df4 which has 8 rows. I use

 `pd.merge(df3, df4, left_on='Type', right_on='type')´ 

therefore. That works perfectly so far, it only stops after 265 rows and doesn't compare the parameters in df4 with all entries in df3

Comment: That might happen if many values in `df3['Type']` have no corresponding value in `df4['type']`. For example, spaces are important. The string  `'boat    '` (with 4 spaces) would not match the string `'boat'` (with no spaces). You need to find a row in `df3` that isn't getting merged and study why its `Type` value isn't in `df3['type']`.